# grouping and disregarding messages in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration application that deals with different trade types in the database which I transform, filter and route to it's appropriate corresponding `tradeEventChannel`

`New RowId->[GateAway]---->|======|----->Transformer->|======|------>Filter->|======|--->Router|======|--->repoTradeChannel`

For one specific trade event type (repoTradeChannel), there are two possible cases:

1. user trades an **open** repo trade, this translates into one repo (open message) `TradeEvent` that should be routed to `repoTradeChannel` for processing. When the trade is termed (hours, days or weeks later), a second messages (the term message) is received and that **should also be processed**.
2. user trades an **term** repo trade, this translates into two repo in the database (open and term message)  `TradeEvent`. However, only one should be routed to `repoTradeChannel` for processing as the second one causes issues. The second one is received into the channel almost lets say within 3 minutes.

In both of the above cases, the `TradeEvent`/ `message` can be grouped by `id` and other properties on the `TradeEvent` class.

My question is, can I use an `aggregator` to group the messages that come in the second case and disregard the second one? I can look at for example the `id` or `action` fields to determine which is not acceptable.  In the second case, the message/event is received within a few minutes, whereas in the first case the second message (term message) can be delayed, hours, days, or weeks.

Is there strategy I can use to handle these cases at aggregation as I cannot stop the incoming messages and filter. I need to rely on grouping, then determining that the second message is not useful in the second case.

what would the implementation look like?  Should I be using a different strategy like caching instead?

In summary, the issue is really how do I differentiate the *term message* that is received in case 1 vs case 2, where case 2 one should be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

You question is too business-specific and it's hard to answer directly without any plain common explanation or code on the matter.

Anyway you really can use an aggregator with the `correlationStrategy` based on that `id` or `action` fields. The `releaseStrategy` should be as simple as `MessageCountReleaseStrategy` with the `threshold = 2`.

What to output from the aggregator you can decide in the `MessageGroupProcessor` implementation: you can merge both messages to a single one. You can still produce a list of them, or just ignore one of the message and produce only the another one.